# I am trying to get the user by the username in the collection of users, the collections.find() always returns null for the mongodb kotlin drivers

Tags: android, mongodb, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

```
//This is my signin routing function
fun Route.signIn(
    userDataSource: UserDataSource,
    hashingService: HashingService,
    tokenService: TokenService,
    tokenConfig: TokenConfig
) {
    post("signin") {
        val request = call.receiveNullable<AuthRequest>() ?: run {
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            return@post
        }

        val user = userDataSource.getUserByUsername(request.username)
        if (user == null) {
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
            return@post
        }

        val isValidPassword = hashingService.verify(
            request.password,
            saltedHash = SaltedHash(
                hash = user.password,
                salt = user.salt
            )
        )
        if (!isValidPassword) {
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
            return@post
        }

        val token = tokenService.generate(
            config = tokenConfig,
            TokenClaim(
                name = "userId",
                value = user.id.toString()
            )
        )
        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK,
            message = AuthResponse(
                token = token
            )
        )
    }
}
```

```
//This is my data source and its functions
package com.example.data.user

import com.mongodb.client.model.Filters
import com.mongodb.kotlin.client.coroutine.MongoDatabase
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*

class MongoUserDataSource(
    db : MongoDatabase
) : UserDataSource {

    private val users = db.getCollection<User>("users")

    override suspend fun getUserByUsername(username: String): User? {
        return users.find(Filters.eq("username", username)).singleOrNull()
    }

    override suspend fun insertUser(user: User): Boolean {
        return users.insertOne(user).wasAcknowledged()
    }
}
```

The insertUser is working fine with returning value of 200 status code and but when the user signin the getUserbyUsername returns null instead of the user. Earlier it was done with collections.findOne() function in KMongo but how it is implemented in MongoDB kotlin driver?